# Запятая перед "и"

Tags: пунктуация

В каких ситуациях ставится запятая  перед союзом "и"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запятая перед "и" ставится в нескольких случаях:
-Если в тексте наличиствует перечисление с повторяюшимся союзом "и".
Пример: *"И жизнь, и слезы, и любовь..."*
-Если "и" стоит после вводного предложения, которое взято в запятые.
Пример: *"Она пришла домой, когда уже стемнело, и этим заставила поволноваться родных"*.
-Если "и" разделяет две части сложносочиненного предложения.
Пример: *"Выпал снег, и лужи покрылись льдом"*.

Answer (score 1):

Сом днем выспится а ночью выходит на охоту:рыбку схватит и рака и лягушку съест

Comment: Ай, молодца)  
Казнить нельзя помиловать

Answer (score 0):

Прежде всего выясним, что может соединять союз "и".

1) Однородные члены предложения(схемы): и О, и О, и О; самая трудная постановка запятой - О, и О, и О.
2) Простые предложения в составе ССП:
*На братских могилах не ставят крестов, и вдовы на них не рыдают*.